# Is it possible to start Mule3 embedded without spring dependency?

Tags: mule

I am trying to use Mule 3.2.1 embedded from a plain java application. The application is suppose to run in an environment where storage space is limited.
I tried something like (import, exceptions omitted for brevity):

```
DefaultMuleContextFactory muleContextFactory = new DefaultMuleContextFactory();  
ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new AutoConfigurationBuilder("mule-config.xml");
MuleContext muleContext = muleContextFactory.createMuleContext(configBuilder);  
muleContext.start();
```

and also this:

```
AutoConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new AutoConfigurationBuilder("mule-config.xml");
DefaultMuleConfiguration configuration = new DefaultMuleConfiguration();
MuleContextBuilder contextBuilder = new DefaultMuleContextBuilder();
contextBuilder.setMuleConfiguration(configuration);
MuleContext muleContext = new DefaultMuleContextFactory().createMuleContext(configbuilder, contextBuilder);
muleContext.start();
```

but both require spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context and some commons libraries. Any help would be great.

Comment: I've reviewed my answer to provide you with the exact Maven configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        MuleContextFactory muleContextFactory = new DefaultMuleContextFactory();
        MuleContextBuilder muleContextBuilder = new DefaultMuleContextBuilder();
        MuleContext muleContext
        muleContextFactory.createMuleContext(muleContextBuilder);
        muleContext.start();

        // create mule client
        MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
        // generate xml request
        String reportRequestXml = createXML(reportRequest);
        // set up message properties
        Map<String, Object> messageProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        messageProperties.put("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        // send request with timeout
        MuleMessage response = client.send(crsRestUrl, reportRequestXml, messageProperties, httpTimeout);

        muleContext.stop();
```

Comment: This doesn't configure Mule, ie no flow, nothing. This is just using the core Mule transports which is not what I thought was the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the XML configuration, you need Spring.

If you don't want to use Spring, your options are:

- Instantiate and wire Mule internal components by hand, dealing with life cycles as well,
- Wait until Mule DSL gets released. You may want to bug MuleSoft about a release date :)

If you only want to use raw transports, ie not configure any flow or pattern, you can do it without Spring but bear in mind that, if the `mule-core` dependency doesn't bring Spring transitively, all the modules and transports do. This means that you'll have to use filtering to keep these dependencies at bay.

For example to use the HTTP transport, you would need these Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

With this in place you then do:

```
MuleContextFactory muleContextFactory = new DefaultMuleContextFactory();
MuleContextBuilder muleContextBuilder = new DefaultMuleContextBuilder();
MuleContext muleContext = muleContextFactory.createMuleContext(muleContextBuilder);
muleContext.start();

MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();

MuleMessage response = client.request("http://www.google.com", 20000L);
System.out.println(response.getPayloadAsString());

muleContext.dispose();
System.exit(0);
```

Note that if that's all you're doing with Mule, then you'd rather use the Apache HTTP Client directly :)

Comment: Thank you David. The url you sent seems to return 404 - would you have another reference?

Comment: So sorry, I didn't realize this was a private link. The DSL would be great for your needs but unfortunately it's not public yet. I reckon you'll have to ask MuleSoft about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I'll go and try to manually instantiate the mule components. Looking forward for the DSL to incarnate in Mulesoft github repo.

Comment: If you get stuck, open a new question and I'll try to help. I've done some barebone Mule config experiments not long ago.

Comment: Cheers David, appreciate that, will do.